# add value to specific object in array by index of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to add value to a specific `object` to the `array` by the `index`?

I wrote this, but of course, it creates a new `object` in the `array`, but I want to insert "errors" to an existing `object` with `index` (on screen it 0 index)

```js
ipcRenderer.on('fileData', (event, data) => {
    this.setState({jobs: [...this.state.jobs, {errors: data}]})
});
```

[image: screen]

Then i wrote this:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('fileData', (event, data) => {
    this.state.jobs.forEach((item, index) => {
        this.setState({jobs: [...this.state.jobs, {errors: item[index] = data}]
    })
    console.log(this.state)
    })
});
```

It inserts a value into the `object`, but without a name and it still creates a new element in the `array`

[image]

I want the result to be like this:

```
jobs: [
    0: {errors: 10, fileName:...}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the index, you can just do

```
const jobs = this.state.jobs.slice(0);
jobs[index].errors = data;
this.setState({jobs});
```

Might have to do more than slice the array, might have to make a deep copy, but yeah, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can make a copy of your array like

```
let jobsCopy = this.state.jobs
```

Then if you know the index you could just do like

```
jobsCopy[index].errors = 10
this.setState({
    jobs: jobsCopy
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the index of the object you want to change.  For example if you know it is the first item in the array you can do this:

```
const indexToChange = 0
this.setState(prevState => prevState.map((obj, i) => {
    if(i === indexToChange) {
        return {
            ...obj,
            errors: data
        }
    } else {
        return obj
    }
}))
```